# safari not loading images outside viewport

Tags: ios, image, viewport

**UPDATE**: PROBLEM existst in desktop Safari too (not only mobile safari)

**FIRST**: there are similar questions but none seem to cover this bug/issue/feature/whatever-apple-calls-it

**PROBLEM**: I have an image-gallery with fullscreen images. So only one image is visible at a time.
When the second view is triggered (navigation or swipe) i would expect the next image to show. This works perfectly in all desktop browsers (IE8+, chrome, firefox.. etc)

**BUT**: on the iPhone the images outside the viewport (offscreen) did not load and they don't load when the view is active:

**EXAMPLE**: http://test.fatih-sahanoglu.de/content/biography

**TEST**: in Desktop browsers (best in chrome) and then on iOS (tested on iOS 7 simulator and real iPhone)

**FUNNY**: first time I got something to work in IE8 but not on iOS (even IE7 gets this correctly even though I don't support it.)

**BTW**:

- using [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for the gallery
- view has `position: fixed`

**WORKS HERE**: http://test.fatih-sahanoglu.de/news (not a carousel)

**SCREENSHOTS**:

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. somehow fixed the issue.

Seems that Safari didn't like that I used `background-image: url(foobar.jpg)`

instead I used `background: url(foobar.jpg)`

I needed to apply `background-size: cover` via JavaScript too to make it work in all browsers (strange strange.. the properties somehow got overwritten by some ghost once I changed the javascript to `background: url(foobar.jpg)` .. ghost = something that I could not find with the web-inspector)

well now it seems to work in Safari

maybe someone can use it

BTW: I needed to do it this way (JavaScript) because of the way the images are applied by Drupal (I really didn't want to write a module just for this feature)